# Need an application for uploading pictures from an iPhone to Picasa Web Albums

Tags: iphone, photos, picasa

I have a strong leaning towards Picasa, but if there's not a great solution out there I can migrate back to Flickr.

Free or pay doesn't matter too much, and I'd like something that allows for tagging.  Geotagging is a plus.

Edit: To be clear, I'd like the app to run natively on the iPhone.

Edit #2: Changed title.

Comment: Can you clarify that you want to upload to Picasa Web, not Picasa, the desktop application?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Mobile Fotos](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284393206&mt=8) (Flickr Browser & Uploader).  Its $2.99, but worth every penny and a few more :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [ShoZu](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewArtist?id=284201063) does everything you want.

Comment: Do you have any experience with it?

Answer (score -1):

I love using [picasa2flickr](http://picasa2flickr.sourceforge.net/) with Picasa. It is a plugin to allow direct uploading to Flickr.

Comment: This is for use on a computer, not an iPhone application.

Comment: Oops. Don't know why i didn't read the whole title properly and pick up on that